# Dispatch inside query or mutations

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to dispatch Redux actions after I get a response from query or mutation.
I found the following suggested methods:

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: { user: null, token: null } as AuthState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      api.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        state.token = payload.token
        state.user = payload.user
      }
    )
  },
})
```

However, I noticed that `api.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled` is not executed if the query returns a cache. What if I want to dispatch the action when the query returns cache?

I know I could use useEffect to perform the dispatch each time the data changes, but is there a better way to do it if I want to complete it within redux?